# Laravel reduce showed Models count

Tags: laravel, relationship, eager-loading

I am trying to optimize some of my pages. Here is my current situation.
There is one table, where I list all Bookmakers. Here are the columns of the table and their types:

```
ID (attribute) | Name (attribute) | Games (relation) | Links (relation) ...
1 | Some name | 5 | 10
```

I have optimized the number of queries by using eager load, unfortunately, on that page, I am loading all relations of each Bookmaker, but I need only the number of each relationship.

Here is my query:

```
return Bookmaker::select(['*'])->withCount(['links', 'games', 'restrictions', 'licenses', 'favourites'])
            ->with(['bonuses', 'links', 'games', 'restrictions', 'licenses', 'favourites']);
```

The debugbar is showing me, that it has loaded also X Bonus models, X Game models, and so on.

How can I disable that load?

Comment: If you want only number of each relation then remove `with()`.

Comment: that doesn't help. It increases the number of queries, but the relations of the Bookmaker are still there

Comment: Are you accessing some of relations data?

Comment: no, I am just showing links_count and etc

Comment: I have made an experiment. Removed the bonuses-relation from the with(). Then in the debugbar I see a query: select * from `bonuses` where `bonuses`.`bookmaker_id` = 190 and `bonuses`.`bookmaker_id` is not null
430μs
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Arr.php:152, which is causing this Model-load, but I don't understand from where is called that?

Comment: Maybe you have got defined `$with` in your model class?

Comment: no, i have used $with in my models. I have similar page, where everything is working fine, but not on that. Do you know what is doing this \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Arr.php:152? Because it is causing the model load accordingly debugbar tool